# Slideshow doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I created a slideshow, which changes the image every 5 seconds.

If a visitor clicks after 4 seconds on "Next", the image will be changed two times in 1 second.

Does anybody know how to reset the interval, after somebody klicked "Next" or "Privious"?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Image = new Array("media/HeaderImage.jpg", "media/HeaderImage2.jpg", "media/HeaderImage3.jpg");

    var Image_Number = 0;
    var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;
    var Image_Intverval;    

    auto();

    function change_image(num)
    {

        Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

        if (Image_Number > Image_Length)
        {
            Image_Number = 0;
        }

        if (Image_Number < 0)
        {
            Image_Number = Image_Length;
        }

        document.slideshow.src= Image[Image_Number];

        clearInterval(Image_Interval);      
        auto();                             

        return false;

    }

    function auto()
    {
        Image_Intverval = setInterval("change_image(1)", 10000);  
    }
```

**Edit:**

Yeah, you're right it's 10 seconds but that's not the point.

Here is the Code for the Links for "Next" and "Previous":

```
<a href="javascript:change_image(1)"><div id="arrowRight"></div></a>
<a href="javascript:change_image(-1)"><div id="arrowLeft"></div></a>
```

Comment: Seems like you've not posted all your code. What is called when the user clicks the next button?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't changed every 5 seconds.(Your code is 10 seconds.) so, you must fix:

```
Image_Intverval = setInterval("change_image(1)", 5000);
```

And if you want to resolve this problem, you must post the code Next or Previous function.